# shibboleth 5 with slapd integration login

Tags: ldap, jetty, saml-2.0, openldap, shibboleth

I have spent 2+ weeks trying to get a Shibboleth 5 IdP stood up for our dev environment.

The players:

- Shibboleth 5 IdP configured to run inside Jetty 11 servlet (no apache)
- openldap (on same server)
- mod_auth_mellon SP on various dev servers

I have gotten the IdP itself working.  I received a 401 unauthorized error trying to navigate to a SAML managed location on a dev server.  This proves the SAML handshake between SP and IdP is working.

My question is:  What Shibboleth 5 configuration do I need to make to have the IdP display a LDAP login page when the SP redirects back to the IdP for authentication?

Further background:
I began by following the Shibboleth 5 wiki for installation.  It is not nearly complete.
I have spent, as I said earlier, 2+ weeks scouring the web for Shibboleth and LDAP tutorials.
None exist for Shibboleth 5.
I found a couple sites working with Shibboleth 3 and slowly cobbled together and modified the old instructions to work with the new v5.
The Shibboleth 5 physical installation does not have a login.jsp page anywhere, nor have I found any mention anywhere of how to get Shib 5 to do a redirect to anything, let alone a local LDAP implementation.
Please help.

I'm not sure which config files will be relevant, so I'll include them as they are asked for.

Comment: Jetty 11 is at End of Community Support - https://github.com/jetty/jetty.project/issues/10485

Comment: "Get the IdP to redirect to a local LDAP implementation" doesn't really make sense; the LDAP server has no UI – it's literally the job _of the IdP itself_ to provide the login UI; there's nowhere else it should be redirecting. All communication to the LDAP server would be done in the backend. So while I can't answer for Shibboleth IdP (we only use the PHP-based SSP as IdP), you really should stop looking for any further "redirects".

Comment: You’re off topic here. Try superuser.com.